# How can I create Data by Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Can i create data haskell with a help of Template Haskell. Data like :

```
data Shape = Circle [Float] Double Int
```

I want write a program, which create Data and then use it

Comment: Try and provide a working example (it doesn't need to compile!) or more context to motivate the question.

Comment: @haoformayor I actually think his question is well formulated, and writing any Template Haskell is quite a burden....  There is very little information available.  It took me days before I could write even the simplest working snippet.

Comment: Just put it inside a splice: `[d| data Shape = Circle [Float] Double Int |]` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example (sorry, I've never figured out how to make template haskell look pretty)....

First, create a library file (this isn't optional, TH requires you to define expressions in a separate file).

```
module DataDefinition where

import Language.Haskell.TH

dataDef::DecsQ
dataDef = do
  return $ --the following is the definition "data Shape = Circle Float | Square"
        [DataD 
                [] 
                (mkName "shape") 
                [] 
                [
                        NormalC (mkName "circle") 
                                [(NotStrict, ConT (mkName "Float"))],
                        NormalC (mkName "Square") []
                ] 
                []
        ]
```

Then, use it like this

```
module Main where

import DataDefinition

$(dataDef)  --This defines Shape

main = do
  let x = Circle 1.0 --Now you can define and use Shape like any other data def....
  return ()
```

---

extra-

You can fill in that last empty array in the DataD creation with deriving instances....  Try changing the `[]` to

```
          [mkName "Show"]
```

and you can print the output in main....

```
main = do
  let x = Circle 1.0
  print x
```